# Is there a macro function of export current open tables to excel?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two tables currently open, and want to export them to excel. Is there a macro function or vba code need to set up without enter specific table names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click menu/band *External data*
2. Click button *Excel*

Comment: Yes, that's `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` but it requires a table/query name - or it would be guessing contest with more than one table open.